# Regex replace not working

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have a string with some HTML/XML in it. All I want to do is to strip the string of all the characters except the ones mentioned in my regular expression.

I want to get rid of all the latin and other letters like 'Â'. The code in the snippet is not working.

Am I missing something?

```js
var essay = "<span style='mso-spacerun:yes'> Â  Â  Â  Â </span>as follows: <br style='mso-special-character:line-break'><![if !supportLineBreakNewLine]><br style='mso-special-character:line-break'><![endif]></span></b><span style='font-family:\"Segoe UI\",\"Lucida Grande\";color:#333333'><o:p></o:p></span></p><p  style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:normal;tab-stops:.5in 1.0in 1.5in 2.0in 2.5in 3.0in 3.5in 4.0in 4.5in 5.0in 5.5in 6.0in 6.5in 7.0in;mso-layout-grid-align:none;text-autospace:none'><span style='font-family:\"Segoe UI\",\"Lucida Grande\";color:#333333'><span style='mso-tab-count:1'> Â  Â  Â  Â  Â  Â  Â  Â  Â  Â  Â  </span>";

essay = essay.replace("/([^A-Za-z0-9></\";=\':#.!,-\]\[\s\(\)&])+/g", " ");

console.log(essay);
```

Comment: Regex is not supposed to be wrapped as string. Trim those double quotes from expression.

Comment: Use a parser (or append your string to the DOM if any) to extract text nodes and process them.

Comment: Thanks @lolbas that worked. don't know what I was thinking.